# How to check from which onResume the user is coming

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a problem. The following Picture visualises my issue. We start in App 1 and press the button. Now we either get to see the screen of app2 or the setting screen. Now when i press the back button (marked as the red circle in app2 and settings) and we get back to the app1 screen. But what i wanna know is from what screen we get back to the app1 screen.

[image]

```
    @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();

        // if(from setting) {
            // do this
           }

            NfcManager manager = (NfcManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NFC_SERVICE);
            NfcAdapter adapter = manager.getDefaultAdapter();
            if (adapter != null && adapter.isEnabled()) {
                   Intent userHomeScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserHomeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(userHomeScreen);

            }
        }



protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nfc_setting);

        NfcManager manager = (NfcManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NFC_SERVICE);
        NfcAdapter adapter = manager.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (adapter != null && adapter.isEnabled()) {
            FirebaseUser currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            if (currentUser != null){
                Intent userHomeScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserHomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(userHomeScreen);
            }else{
                Intent loginScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(loginScreen);
            }
        }
        else {
            btn_nfc_navigate_setting = findViewById(R.id.btn_nfc_navigate_setting);

            btn_nfc_navigate_setting.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NFC_SETTINGS));
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: What is the logic for the back button press in both activities? Add the code to your question.

Comment: @HasanBouTaam there is no back logic. at least one that I did not program, because I only press the back button and it goes back. Or what do you mean?

 :D

Comment: Show me the code where you open AppB and settings.

Comment: @HasanBouTaam sure! Please see my edit! :) Settings open `startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NFC_SETTINGS));` and the other app open `Intent loginScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(loginScreen);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look now that I understand whats going on, you have to `startActivityForResult()` not `startActivity()`:

Now in the activity that you use to open other activities:

**When you open Log in screen:**

```
Intent loginScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
int requestCode = 10;
startActivityForResult(loginScreen , requestCode);
```

**When you open settings**

```
btn_nfc_navigate_setting.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
int requestCode = 11;
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NFC_SETTINGS) , requestCode);
}
});
```

**Override this method to listen to from where you came instead of `onResume()`**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

//this is triggered when you come back to this activity
if(requestCode == 10){

//we came from login


}else if(requestCode == 11){

//we came from settings

}


}
```

Comment: Is there an option to stay in touch with you?

Answer (score 0):

Use `startActivityForResult()`

From App1 to App2 or Setting:

```
int FLAG_APP2 = 1
Intent i = new Intent(this, App2.class);
startActivityForResult(i, FLAG_APP2);
```

Then in App2 button back tapped:

```
finish();
```

Then in App1 override `onActivityResult()`:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == FLAG_APP2) {
        //here you know this is from App2 Screen
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you tell me if the user comes from the settings, how would I write it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the result of an Intent (in this case settings or app2), you can use

`startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)`

instead of

`startActivity(intent)`.

Where request code should be unique for different intents (in this case settings and app2).

To handle the result you have to override the onActivityResult() in the actvity.

So your required code will be

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    // if(from setting) {
        // do this
        // }

        NfcManager manager = (NfcManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NFC_SERVICE);
        NfcAdapter adapter = manager.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (adapter != null && adapter.isEnabled()) {
               Intent userHomeScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserHomeActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(userHomeScreen,1);

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 1) {
        //    Activity returned from userHomeScreen
        }
        else if (requestCode ==2) {
        //    Activity returned from Settings
        }
    }
```

UPDATE:

To add to that above if you want to access any Settings FEATURE you can use SETTINGS Constants as intent parameters.

[Settings Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#constants)

For example, if you want to access NFC settings:

```
// Look into the constants in the documentation to know which constants to use in intent
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NFC_SETTINGS);
startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You wrote that the code should be unique. By settings I mean the right settings from the cell phone. Is there a kind of "unique" settings intents here?

Comment: Based on what content in the settings you are trying to accept. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I have updated the answers, based on your comment. If it satisfies to your question, please upvote and mark this as answer.